# Problems with rendering the results of searching in Symfony 5.4

Tags: symfony, search, repository

I've recently started learning Symfony (from Documentation and Google;) so I have a lot of problems.
I want to search for games according to selected attributes (name, category, age, number of players, price, deposit). In SearchController I've created a form and in Game (Gra) Repository I built a QueryBuilder which I am trying to call in SearchController and render to search/result.twig.html
I am probably making a lot of mistakes, I try to fix them one by one, the last one is this:

Method name must be a string in this verse:
$ Games = $ this -> $ repository (Game :: class) -> findByField ($ Name, $ id_Category, $ Number of players, $ Age_of_years, $ Price, $ Deposit);

Is this because some of the fields are int? But anyway, even if I changed it to string, I can't render it ...
There are a lot of people with experience here, so I count on your help :)

```html
MY GRA GAMEREPOSITORY

 public function  findByExampleField(?string $Nazwa,string $id_Kategoria,string $Liczba_graczy,string $Wiek_od_lat, int $Cena, int $Kaucja)

    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->andwhere('a.Nazwa = :Nazwa')
        ->orWhere('a.id_Kategoria = :Kategoria')
        ->orWhere('a.Liczba_graczy = :Liczba graczy')
        ->orWhere('a.Wiek_od_lat = :Wiek od lat')
        ->orWhere('a.Cena = :Cena')
        ->orWhere('a.Kaucja = :Kaucja')
        ->setParameter(':Nazwa', $Nazwa)
        ->setParameter(':Kategoria', $id_Kategoria)
        ->setParameter(':Liczba graczy', $Liczba_graczy)
        ->setParameter(':Wiek od lat', $Wiek_od_lat)
        ->setParameter(':Cena', $Cena)
        ->setParameter(':Kaucja', $Kaucja);

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        return $query->execute();
    }
```

```html
MY SEARCHCONTROLLER

{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'app_search')]
  
    

    public function searchAction(Request $request, GraRepository $repository, string $Nazwa='Nazwa',string $id_Kategoria="Kategoria",string $Liczba_graczy='Liczba_graczy',string $Wiek_od_lat ='Wiek_od_lat', string $Cena = 'Cena', string $Kaucja = 'Kaucja'):Response

    {

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder([])
        ->add('Nazwa', EntityType::class, ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Nazwa gry:', 'class' => Gra:: class ] )
        
        ->add('id_Kategoria', EntityType::class,  ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Kategoria:', 'class' => Kategoria:: class])
         
        
        ->add('Liczba_graczy', EntityType::class, ['required' => false, 'label' => 'Liczba graczy:', 'class' => Gra:: class,'choice_label' => 'Liczba_graczy','expanded' => true,  'multiple'=> false,
        
        'query_builder' => function (GraRepository $repository) 
        {

            return $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->select('l')
            ->groupBy('l.Liczba_graczy');

        } ]) 
      ADDING A FEW MORE FIELDS (...)
       
        } ]) 

        ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
         
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
        
        {
            $form = $request->request->get('Nazwa', 'id_Kategoria', 'Liczba_graczy', 'Wiek_od_lat', 'Cena', 'Kaucja');


            $Gry=$this->$repository(Gra::class)-> findByField ($Nazwa,$id_Kategoria,$Liczba_graczy,$Wiek_od_lat, $Cena, $Kaucja);
   
            if (!$Gry) {
               throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                   'Taka gra nie istnieje'
               );
         
               }

               return $this->render('search/result.html.twig', ['Gry' => $Gry]);
            }

        return $this->render('search/advsearch.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([ 
            'data_class' => Gra::class,
        ]);
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Did you try dumping each parameters from your method `findByExampleField` ? Is one of the value null ?

Comment: Did you try `return $query->getResult();` instead of `return $query->execute();`. Your hydrator is null.